# preload elements with none displaying div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to preload all my Elements before manipulating them with jquery and co.
i considered that i could make a div with `display: none` and put all elements in there which im using for my site.

```
<div id="preload" style="display: none">
     <img src="1.png" />
     <img src="bla.gif" />
     <img src="another_one.png" />
     <img src="cutelittlekitten.png" />
</div>
```

and then this to fade in my site.

```
$('#preload img').load(function() { 
        /* Site fades in all elements are preloaded */ 
});
```

is there any disadvantage to do it like that? and if, why and maybe another better solution?

**edit: i would like to pre-cache the images!**

Comment: Your handler will fire when any of the images is loaded, not wait for all of them to be loaded. So you'll need to keep track and determine when all are done.

Comment: Disadvantage: use sees a blank page until everything is loaded.

Comment: despite the fact with blank page. i would build some kind of preload element before!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, are you trying to pre-cache your images for performance?

Comment: yeah exactly what i want to!

Answer (score 1):

Disadvantage is you're making people wait. Just lazy load your images instead - any image above the fold you use a legit `src` attribute, and any image below the fold, you do something like this:

`<img class="lazyload" src="images/clear.gif" data-src="path/to/real/image.jpg" />`

Then you could use a plugin like this or write your own to fade in images with the class 'lazyload' on scroll if they appear in the visible window region:

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

You could also simply lazy load all those images on `window.load` so they'll begin to fade in after the above-the-fold images are visible and ready.